# Ubuntu 22.04 wifi and ethernet are not working after update Feb 27th

Tags: wireless, 22.04, ethernet

I updted Ubuntu 22.04 on Feb 27th. Now wifi ando ethernet are not parking. It shows connected but I I don't have internet access. I try to boot from old kernel versión but it didn't work. Please help me

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:db:55:c7:2c:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:7b:a1:8b:f1:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.171/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 7103sec preferred_lft 7103sec
4: gpd0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:3b:a5:ea:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-f61436ed76f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:55:a7:2e:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.23.0.1/16 brd 172.23.255.255 scope global br-f61436ed76f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-92c2912e1266: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e8:2e:0a:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-92c2912e1266
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:e8ff:fe2e:aa7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br-520bc9e6fd49: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2b:a4:b3:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-520bc9e6fd49
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: br-6423d184c65a: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d1:2b:e8:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-6423d184c65a
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: veth42589bb@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-92c2912e1266 state UP group default 
    link/ether 3e:3f:88:36:7e:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::3c3f:88ff:fe36:7eb8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: veth9675f15@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-92c2912e1266 state UP group default 
    link/ether c6:75:4b:a1:bf:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::c475:4bff:fea1:bfd2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4462]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**ls -al /etc/resolv.conf**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 may  4  2021 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1457092/edit) to include the complete output of `ip a` and also of `iwconfig`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @user535733 Most likely it was a kernel upgrade to 5.19 that broke some driver.

Comment: Please add: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 I added the output for ip a

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the output

Comment: @chili555 I added the output

Comment: What does `ethtool enp3s0f1` say? Also output of `lshw -C network` please.